# conemu + ssh clears console history

Tags: ssh, conemu

I am using ConEmu and am totally satisfied with it except for the fact that if I use PuTTY for SSH access, I can then run commands on the remote machine like vim or nano or mcedit or others which opens some kind of a curses-interface and I can see the console commands history, but when I use CygWin SSH client or OpenSSH for Windows I cannot see the commands history anymore after running vim/nano/mcedit/whatever else.

When I quit those programs (:wq in vim, Esc key in mcedit, Ctrl^X in nano) I can see all the previous commands executed, like this (if I use PuTTY):

1. Run PuTTY and connect to some host
2. You will see something like that in history:
   host$ whoami
   user
   host$ vim
   ...do something in vim then press :wq

And you should see exactly this:

=== Cut ===
host$ whoami
user
host$ vim
host$
=== Cut ===

all the previous commands (whoami) are visible. However if I run ConEmu and then use SSH client from CygWin (or OpenSSH client, it doesn't matter) the following happens:

1. Run ConEmu
2. ssh user@somehost
   host$ whoami
   user
   host$ vim
   ...do something in vim then press :wq

And now the screen is empty! No history! You just see this:

=== Cut ===
host$
=== Cut ===

As if no whoami was executed. Same happens for mcedit, nano or any other programs that has something like a "screen". Also same happens with Ctrl-O in Midnight Commander, in PuTTY everything is nice, but when using ssh from CygWin in ConEmu (or OpenSSH Windows client) and running Midnight Commander each Ctrl-O just shows an empty history. As if nothing was typed previously. That is really not nice at all.

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

The standard `TERM` environment variable for `PuTTY.exe` is `xterm` and that will mostly work for *Cygwin* `ssh.exe` as well.  However, a better `TERM` environment variable for `ssh.exe` is `cygwin`.

When you use *Cygwin* `ssh.exe` to connect to another system, *Cygwin* processes your escape sequences, not *ConEmu*.  In fact you get the same behavior whether you are running `ssh.exe` inside or outside of *ConEmu*.  So the problem is not really related to *ConEmu* at all, at least not its ANSI processor.

The solution is to use the `cygwin` for the `TERM` environment variable on the remote system.  In fact, the *SSH* client and server cooperate to do this for you automatically.  But perhaps you have accidentally overridden the supplied `TERM` variable with say `xterm` in your `.bash_profile` or whatever.  In that case, the escape sequence to restore the screen buffer after exiting the editor won't be correct for the *Cygwin* ANSI processor.

You can do this test to check whether this solves your problem:

```
$ export TERM=xterm
$ vim
$ # the screen before is cleared
$ export TERM=cygwin
$ vim
$ # the screen buffer is restored
```

Comment: This didn't work for me when I SSH into an EC2 Server running Ubuntu: export TERM=cygwin
➜  ~
zle-line-init:echoti:1: no such terminfo capability: smkx