# Keep ConEmu screen buffer after exiting vim

Tags: vim, vi, conemu

[image: screenshot from conEmu settings]I am using ConEmu/cmder on my windows 10 machine, Whenever I open/edit a file using vim and exit the screen gets cleared and doesn't save the previous state/contents. Is there a way to resume my work where I left from. It works well on my Ubuntu machine with Terminal as well as Terminator.

There is no .vimrc or _vimrc file in my %HOME% directory or anywhere else, any suggestions.
 The vimrc is located under "C:\Users\\Downloads\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\etc\vimrc"

but any changes to that doesn't seem to be taking any effect.

So far I have't found any specific post or solution to this problem

Here is one post I am referring to: https://superuser.com/questions/196055/how-to-replace-vim-screen-buffer-with-previous-bash-activity-after-quitting

Comment: What is the `TERM` environment variable set to in your shell?

Comment: There is no environment variable named TERM currently set  on my Windows machine. Shall I create one?

Comment: That environment variable controls the terminal emulation for Vim, so you need to find the right setting for ConEmu/cmder and set it in order for alternate screen to work (if it's even possible in that program(. Googling didn't tell me the correct setting, which is why I asked.

Comment: Added a screen shot from settings->Environment , Looks like ConEmu/cmder is running out of  an executable directly and not being installed anywhere, hence there is nothing under system environmental variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a temporary solution to my problem:

[conemu + ssh clears console history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207673/conemu-ssh-clears-console-history) did the trick , it's just that for me the following worked :

```
$ export TERM=xterm
$ vim
$ # the screen before is restored
$ export TERM=cygwin
$ vim
$ # the screen buffer is cleared
```

My default TERM was set to cygwin after changing it to xterm ConEmu works as expected.